# Query to populate a field with different name in data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

I am newbie in SQL, but i have to populate one data extension (name = TEST A) from another data extension (name = TEST B).

The fields in 'TEST B' has name like: 
1. Name
2. State
3. Email Address
4. Id.account

The fields in 'TEST A' has name like:

1. Name
2. State
3. Email Address
4. Subscriber Key

I want to populate the DE 'TEST A' according the exactly name in common. And the records in 'ID.accout' (field in 'Test B') goes to field 'Subscriber Key' (in TEST A').

Someone could help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to fill in TEST A 'Subscriber Key' field with the info from 'TEST B' 'ID.account' field, then the following will do it for you:

```
SELECT Name
       , State
       , [Email Address]
       , [ID.account] as [Subscriber Key]
FROM [TEST B]

/* Target DE: TEST A */
```

Judging from comments - If you want to include ID.account in the query as well, just include `, [ID.account]` before the `FROM`and add the ID.account field to TEST A DE.

Comment: So thanks, Gortonington!!! One more question: can i duplicate the records that has, for example, the 'name' field. The records 'Test B' appears in 'Test A' fill in collumn 'name' and other field?

Comment: Sorry not sure I get what you mean by that.

Comment: so you are saying you want to compare data in A and B and only fill in the data from A if it matches in existing data in B?

Comment: If i can fill the record in two collumns inside Target Data Extension like example above: 

The fields in 'TEST B' has name like: 
1. Name 
2. State 
3. Email Address 
4. Id.account

The fields in 'TEST A' has name like:

1. Name
2. State
3. Email Address
4. Subscriber Key
5. ID.account

Can i fill the 'ID.account' and 'Subscriber Key' in 'Test A' like the same records? In the case is 'Id.account' from 'Test B'

Comment: updated answer to reflect your comments